# Most Efficient Way to Pop Bubbles

Tags: bubbles

I was bathing the kids the other night, and used more bubble bath than normal. Being small, they got a bit freaked out by the enormous piles of bubbles that they had to sit in. To try to diffuse the situation, I showed them a few ways to try to flatten out the foam, destroy the bubbles and making the bath a bit more like they're used to.

This got me to thinking... what's the most efficient way to 'destroy' bubble foam?

Methods I tried:

- Pour water onto the foam (through a toy that has a sort of colander pattern of holes in it)
- Pat the foam down with a cupped hand and push the foam into the water
- Place a flannel onto the foam and try to push that down onto the surface of the water
- put foam between hands and clap
- generally splash about in and around the foam
- (various incidents of making bubble beards, funny hair styles etc, but I'm not sure they're so relevant here...?)

I'm guessing the surface area of my hand, versus the spray pattern of the colander has some bearing on the result, so I guess we need to assume that the scale of whatever we're doing is the same in all cases.

Some methods presumably create bubbles at the same time as destroying them. However I'd say larger bubbles are more easily popped than smaller foam, so presumably we'd have a net-gain in that sort of case. I guess we'd need to consider the number of bubbles popped by any action, versus the volume of foam, though.

Lastly, I know that various chemicals can be used to destroy foam (including soap), but let's assume we're not going to add anything else to my kids bathwater. I guess I'm after physical destruction rather than chemical ;-)

Comment: I don't really see a physics question here.

Comment: i think you have to dry your hands then just tap them!!

Comment: For this you also need to consider , how bubbles were formed as first.

Comment: Just use your hair dryer on the bubbles!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [de-foaming agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defoamer) added to the water

Comment: OP says explicitly that they don't want chemicals...

Comment: @KyleKanos Well, in that case a blowtorch works REALLY well! Problem solved

Comment: But then you'd have a ruined bathroom.

Comment: _Well, in that case a blowtorch works REALLY well!_ My sentiments exactly,  Dirk.

Answer (score -4):

> Most Efficient Way to Pop Bubbles

Most efficient is a little ambiguous, in that we could be talking about the cheapest method, or the fastest, et cetera. But no matter, I'll go with the flow.

> I was bathing the kids the other night, and used more bubble bath than normal. Being small, they got a bit freaked out by the enormous piles of bubbles that they had to sit in. To try to diffuse the situation, I showed them a few ways to try to flatten out the foam, destroy the bubbles and making the bath a bit more like they're used to.

Nice.

> This got me to thinking... what's the most efficient way to 'destroy' bubble foam? Methods I tried: Pour water onto the foam (through a toy that has a sort of colander pattern of holes in it). Pat the foam down with a cupped hand and push the foam into the water...

There's lots of other things you could have tried. Such as cold water from the shower hose. Spraying them with deodorant. The list goes on.

> Some methods presumably create bubbles at the same time as destroying them. However I'd say larger bubbles are more easily popped than smaller foam, so presumably we'd have a net-gain in that sort of case. I guess we'd need to consider the number of bubbles popped by any action, versus the volume of foam, though.

Yep. Mechanical agitation is how you make bubbles. You need to go the other way. Take a tip Peter Diehr and his hair dryer...

> Lastly, I know that various chemicals can be used to destroy foam (including soap), but let's assume we're not going to add anything else to my kids bathwater. I guess I'm after physical destruction rather than chemical ;-)

What you need is a tank of hydrogen and a tank of oxygen and some appropriate tubing. When the hydrogen and oxygen react together the result is pure clean water. And to make them react, you simply apply a spark of some kind:

***ROAARRRRRRRRR!***

That'll soon take care of them bubbles. What you need Ralph, is a  *flamethrower*.